# SSRS: Repeat Down Total from Matrix in all rows

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Need some help in SSRS,

New to this so apologies ahead if not entirely up to scratch with answers.

I am trying to get the Total of a column and repeat the value of that total (Total Checks - see image) across all the rows.

Below is image:

[image]

I have tried multiple different ways, each time with failure.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Please include at least a sample of your original data set.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for getting back. By including a sample data set. Do you mean somehow extracting the dataset from SSRS? Or extracting the data I am using on to a spreadsheet and sharing? Apologies again for amateur answers.

Comment: What we need to know is what data is coming from your SSRS dataset and what you expect the results to look like, with an explanation is anything is not obvious. When I say obvious, I mean to somebody who has never seen your data.

Comment: @GonnerDev; You SSRS data is sourced from somewhere (presumably a database). Do a query on the database table and paste the first 10 or so lines of the result (the non-sensitive stuff) here. Only then can someone possibly help you know how to help you condition your data appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where you are getting your data from, you have different options.  For example, within SQL you could use windowed functions:

```
select Date
      ,Checker
      ,sum(Checker) over () as TotalChecks
      ,sum(Checker) over (partition by Date) as TotalChecksByDate
from table
```

or within SSRS expressions by explicitly stating your scope, either for the dataset as a whole:

```
=sum(Fields!Checker.Value, "YourDataset")
```

or just for the grouping within your table:

```
=sum(Fields!Checker.Value, "YourTableGroupName")
```

Comment: Hi 'iamdave', I have used: =sum(Fields!Checker.Value, "YourDataset") and it seems to work great, only issue i am having is that this is only when i have filters applied for specific entities. When i remove the filters in sums across all Entities. Sorry for a new questions and all help much appreciated!

Comment: @GonnerDev  To tag a user in your comment start the name with an @ symbol.  Your second question seems more complex and will therefore need a lot more contextual explanation.  Please mark this answer as correct for this issue and start another question with the relevant details of what you currently have and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you! I will be sure to do so.